# Android: How block execution of activity until locationupdate()?

Tags: android, android-activity, gps

I need to block (no input, no go on) the execution of an Activity until I have the GPS coordinate. How can I do?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you can just run the AsyncTask(with your updates) with the progress dialog bundled. The activity will be blocked by the dialog.

See the examples here:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html 
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ProgressDialog.html

another useful example:

http://www.screaming-penguin.com/node/7746

UPDATE:

```
Location location = null;
while(location != null) {
  location = requestLocation();
}
```

Comment: When I call the method requestLocationUpdates(...) if the location is not update the method also returns. So I would to block this method until I have a location latitude and longitude because they are necessary for the next Activity.

Comment: Location object is not null but it hasn't coordinate. If I do this(the while) on the coordinate the application crash.